# How do I remove a usb device?

Tags: usb, disconnect

I've got a controller hooked up that is a pain to unplug. It's a steering wheel with pedals and in some applications/games it acts like I'm holding down on a joystick. When I'm in Windows I simply open devices & printers, right click the icon for the steering wheel and select remove. How can I do this on Ubuntu? Preferably with an easy command I can alias.

Answer (score 4):

Open nautilus. In the side bar is a list of external drives. Click the Eject (⏏) button.

If you can't see this, press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image]

This only applies to storage devices.

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Run the command `xinput`:

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜    Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜    Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse   id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜    Microsoft Trackball Explorer®              id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
     Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     Power Button                               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     UVC Camera (046d:08c9)                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     Eee PC WMI hotkeys                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

You should be able to see it there, for example my mouse is a `Microsoft Trackball Explorer®` and it has an id of `10`.

Yours will also have an id. Run the following command:

```
xinput disable <ID>
```

then to enable it (if you want)

```
xinput enable <ID>
```

a restart also resets this, so they will all become active again.

Comment: I doubt that `a steering wheel with pedals` comes up in Nautilus - or does it ;-] ?

Comment: Just reread. Good point, will edit.

Comment: It's not showing up under xinput for some reason, but it is definitely accepting input. This is what I get from xinput: http://i.imgur.com/e5VS15o.png

Comment: What about disabling 9 + 10? Be careful, that might be your keyboard... I'm just thinking it might identify as both.

Comment: Remove it **once** and compare to the `xinput` output as you have it removed.

Comment: @Hannu What do you mean?

Comment: @Hannu I removed it, rebooted, and there is no change in xinput. It is still disconnected.

Comment: @Tim. =) changed that. e.g. `xinput >with_device`, remove it to run `xinput >without_device` and then `diff -u0 with_device without_device` afterwards.

Comment: @Spaisekraft - ouch. How about comparing `lsusb` output then? Does that help? Is there other means to disable USB-devices?

Comment: `lsusb` - just been researching. I can't disable any device with it.

Comment: No, not with lsusb itself - but there might be something else, given the ouput of lsusb for the device.